# Laravel Error Page with $app context

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-codes

I want to create a custom error page for 4xx http status codes (eg. 404, 400, ...).
But I need the whole $app context, since I want to display my header, footer and a search field.

I have read a lot about the custom solutions in the app/start/global.php file, but this does not help. Its good for the 5xx status codes, since I do not need the $app context there (in most cases I couldn't be accessed anyways, if there was a 500).

This is fine for the 5xx:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if (App::isDownForMaintenance()) {
        return Response::make("Maintenance, brb.", 503);
    }

    if (Config::get('app.debug')) return;

    switch ($code)
    {  
        case 500: /* internal error */
        default:
            return View::make('_layouts.error_500');
    }
});
```

But how can I create a 4xx custom page with $app in Laravel?

My Laravel Version is: 4.2.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use `App::missing()` for that:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    $app = app();
    return Response::view('errors.missing', compact('app'), 404);
});
```

More info:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-404-errors

Comment: But this will create a new app, right? My whole set up will be gone in this case right, since the global.php ist called before $app gets created?

Comment: What exactly do you need $app for in a view?

Comment: app() should return the current instance.

Comment: I do not need it in a view, I need it to create that view. The header and footer require some stuff, generated by $app and/or the BaseController, which won't be executed if I render a just a (static) 404-View

Comment: The app is as much ready inside the closure as it is in any other controller.